# Unable to establish connectivity on a port after configuring proper rules

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, network-security-groups

I have a Linux VM on azure, which I can access using SSH without any issues. I needed access to another port(lets say 7077) from outside, and here is what i have done so far, but unable to establish connectivity

1. Created an inbound rule from the networking settings, it created the rule on the Network security Group attached to the network interface.
2. Added a new Network Security Group, attached it to the Subnet

If I do a netcat request on port 22, i get a successful connectivity, but for the port 7077 I get connection refused.

Also with IP flow verification passes for the port

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Do not post images of these things. They are not searchable and cause accessibility concerns. Write out what you have done instead. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow that same port in the firewall settings of the VM. The OS itself is what is refusing the connection suggesting you have not setup any firewall rules to allow that port.

Try adding a allow rule in the firewall settings and see if you can reach that port.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/iptables-add-rule/

Ubuntu 17.04
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html

Comment: sudo iptables -L shows that its already  empty. And since its ubuntu i also checked the status of ufw, which is also inactive.

Comment: What distribution and version of Linux are you running

Comment: Ubuntu Server 17.04

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html

Check the link to manage the firewall settings for Ubuntu. The commands are different from the -iptables information above

Comment: Also see similar thread https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message

Comment: ufw service was disabled. but i did enable it and allowed 22 and 7077, i can connect to 22 , but not 7077..

Comment: It might be actually cos nothing is listening to the port. I will go ahead and accept your answer.

Comment: Kind of what I was starting to think. I spun up a Ubunut 17.04 and every time I opened the port and added an allow rule i got refused. But it was in fact reaching the VM. Once you have something listening on the port I would love to hear it that was the main cause.